# Почему изменяется кодировка текста при отправке письма?

Tags: php, email, openserver

Установлена сборка openServer. 
В php - скрипте я обрабатываю поля, введённые из формы сначала с помощью trim, затем strip_tags, а затем - htmlentities.

Например: `$arr[mail] = htmlentities(strip_tags(trim($_POST[userEmail])));`

Затем пытаюсь из функцией `mail` отправить письмо с полями из формы. Заголовки такие:

```
From: no-reply@sdstrategy.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Письмо отправляется, но если ввести в поля ввода русский текст, меняется кодировка всего текста в письме. На реальном сервере поля ввода пользователя в письме отображаются в неверной кодировке, а остальной текст - нормально.

Например:

Письмо на локалке с русским текстом в полях ввода формы:

```
To: andrey.xwz@mail.ru
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?0KDQtdCz0LjRgdGC0YDQsNGG0LjRjyDQvdCwINGB0LDQudGC0LUg0JrRg9C70LjQvdC40Ycu0YHRgtGA0LDRgtC10LPQuNGH0LXRgdC60LDRj9Cy0YHRgtGA0Y/RgdC60LAu0YDRhA==?=
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:reg.php
From: no-reply@sdstrategy.com 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Р¤.Р.Рћ: &Ntilde;„&Ntilde;‹&ETH;&sup2;&Ntilde;„&Ntilde;‹&ETH;&sup2;<br/>РљРѕРјРїР°РЅРёСЏ: &Ntilde;„&Ntilde;‹&ETH;&sup2;&Ntilde;„&Ntilde;‹&ETH;&sup2;<br/>РўРµР»РµС„РѕРЅ: 89525045972<br/>Email: asd@asd.asd<br/>РџР°РєРµС‚: Р’РёРґРµРѕР·Р°РїРёСЃСЊ - 8500 СЂСѓР±.<br/>РЎРµРјРёРЅР°СЂ: РљР°Рє СЂР°Р·СЂР°Р±РѕС‚Р°С‚СЊ РјР°СЂРєРµС‚РёРЅРіРѕРІС‹Р№ РїР»Р°РЅ РЅР° 2016 РіРѕРґ РІ СѓСЃР»РѕРІРёСЏС… РЅРµРѕРїСЂРµРґРµР»С‘РЅРЅРѕСЃС‚Рё?<br/>РњРµСЃС‚Рѕ Рё РґР°С‚Р°: Р§РµР»СЏР±РёРЅСЃРє, 25 С„РµРІСЂР°Р»СЏ (+8500)<br/>Р”РѕРїРѕР»РЅРёС‚РµР»СЊРЅС‹Рµ СѓСЃР»СѓРіРё: РС‚РѕРіРѕ: 8500 СЂСѓР±.
```

А вот письмо, отосланное с реального сервера на почту:

```
Ф.И.О: Ñ�Ñ�Ð²Ñ�Ñ�Ð²
Компания: Ñ�Ñ�Ð²Ñ�Ð²Ñ�
Телефон: aasdad
Email: asd@asd.asd
Пакет: Видеозапись - 8500 руб.
Семинар: Как разработать маркетинговый план на 2016 год в условиях неопределённости?
Место и дата: Челябинск, 25 февраля (+8500)
Семинар: Системный подход к управлению эффективностью маркетинга
Место и дата: Челябинск, 24 марта (+8500)
Дополнительные услуги: Итого: 17000 руб.
```

В html -файле, в которой находится форма с полями ввода кодировка - utf-8. На сервере в htaccess - тоже utf-8. Из-за чего изменяется кодировка?

Answer (score 1):

попробуй в тег "" прописать accept-charset="utf-8" `<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">`

Comment: Убрал htmlentities - русский текст стал отображаться нормально